# CAMEL imap component: invalid provider

Tags: email, apache-camel, imap, blueprint-osgi

This is the route:

```
<route id="reading1">
    <from uri="timer:timerName?period=50000"/>
    <to uri="imap://server/?username=My_@mail&amp;password=My_password"/>
    <log message="${body}"/>
  </route>
```

when i run it i got this error:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: invalid provider
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:724)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:668)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:648)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.DefaultJavaMailSender.getTransport(DefaultJavaMailSender.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.DefaultJavaMailSender.send(DefaultJavaMailSender.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailProducer.process(MailProducer.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:304)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:152)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:73)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
[ thread #0 - timer://timerName] TimerConsumer                  WARN  Error processing exchange. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by: [javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException - invalid provider]
```

when i change it to  :

```
<route id="reading1">
    <from uri="imap://server/?username=My_@mail&amp;password=My_password"/>
    <log message="${body}"/>
  </route>
```

it works 
it seems imap component can not be in a `<to../>`  tag only `<from ../>` tag and in my case imap params (username and password) come from anothers endpoints before Imap.
How can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `smtp` when sending email, `imap` and `pop3` is for receiving emails. `smtp` is for sending.

Yeah a bit confusing.

We should maybe have it called just `mail` and then default to imap for consumer and smtp for sending in Camel.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Claus ! Each period i have to read mails from many users and transform them to sms. The imap params (username and password ) come from text file like this: `<from uri="file:Uri"/>
    <split>
      <tokenize token="\n"></tokenize>
      <to uri="bean:com.ngtrend.mailtosms.Filetransform?method=extract(Exchange)"/> // to extract @mail and pass  and put them in headers
<to uri="imap://server/?username=${header.adressemail}&amp;password={header.password}"/>` .......invoke SMS webservice...i got this message : `javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: invalid provider`

Comment: i tried a basic examlpe with Timer and iMap endpoints (as in the first post) and i found that we can only consume events from this iMap endpoint. is it right ?

Comment: Use <to uri="smtp:xxx..."/>